# Graphing and comparing two data sets

Tags: statistics, histogram

I have 2 sets of data
In both the sets, each element is in between 0 and 1000.

1. 130 elements
2. 75 elements

My professor wants me to plot a "graph" which will allow him to compare these two sets of data.

I plotted a histogram, but since there are two different numbers of data ( 130 and 75), it was of no use.

1. What is the graph that I should plot which will show the relating between these two sets of data?
2. How do I "normalize" the data so that it looks like both data have some common details which can be compared?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only one variable: value, 
I would have density graphs for value range so that you could see that  25% of all values fall between 0-250 in one data set but only 20% of the other falls within the same range . These could be pie chart or a bar graph.